# Using React Navigation for a Navigator inside a Screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

In my react native app, I have a stack navigator as so:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: AppTabs,
    Account: AccountScreen,
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
    Post: PostScreen,
  },
);
```

The ProfileScreen contains some header content and another TabNavigator, in a layout similar to when you click on a channel in Youtube:

```
const ProfileTabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: ProfileHome,
    Posts: ProfileMade,
  },
);

const ProfileNav = createAppContainer(ProfileTabs);

class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View>Some header content</View>
        <ProfileNav />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that I am unable to navigate from inside the ProfileTabs navigator to a screen in the original stacknavigator. E.g. if a user clicks on a post in the ProfileMade screen, I want to navigate them to the PostScreen.

Please can someone tell me what should be changed? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to another stack sending the name of stack on the **.navigate()** method:

```
navigation.navigate('StackName', {
  screen: 'YourScreenName'
});
```

Comment: This isn't working for some reason. I am still only able to navigate the Home and Posts screen in the ProfileNav with `navigation.navigate()`. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to navigate to another stack?

Comment: It just doesn't do anything - the screen stays the same

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for navigation?